# How to reduce used memory for a repetitive optimization constraint in python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, ram, cvxpy

I have a mathematical optimization problem of the following simplified form:

```
min ∑Pxy
s.t. Pxy≥Pyz, ∀x,y,z
Pxy ∈ {0,1}
```

This problem has X*Y*Z constraints. I write the following code to perform the optimization. The only way that came to my mind was introducing two new matrices that by multiplication with the vectors Pxy and Pyz repeat the constraints. These matrices have size of (XYZ* YZ) and (XYZ* XY). As the dimensions of the problem increases the size of these matrices will become huge and my RAM cannot handle it. Is it possible to re-write this code in a way that requires less memory for constraints? (Probably less memory usage might lead to faster speed).

The following code used all of the RAM on google colab and crashed! (while the optimization problem is easy and can be solved by hand)

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(55)
X_max, Y_max, Z_max = 70, 70, 50

P_yz = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(Y_max, Z_max), p=[9./10, 1./10])
P_yz = P_yz.reshape(-1)

z_repetition = np.zeros((X_max, Y_max, Z_max, X_max, Y_max), dtype=np.int8)
for x in range(X_max):
  for y in range(Y_max):
    for z in range(Z_max):
      z_repetition[x,y,z,x,y] = 1
z_repetition = z_repetition.reshape(X_max * Y_max * Z_max, -1)

x_repetition = np.zeros((X_max, Y_max, Z_max, Y_max, Z_max), dtype=np.int8)
for x in range(X_max):
  for y in range(Y_max):
    for z in range(Z_max):
      x_repetition[x,y,z,y,z] = 1
x_repetition = x_repetition.reshape(X_max * Y_max * Z_max, -1)

P_xy = cp.Variable((X_max * Y_max), boolean=True)
constraints = [] 
constraints.append(z_repetition * P_xy >= np.matmul(x_repetition, P_yz))
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum(P_xy)), constraints) 
objective = problem.solve(verbose=True)
# print(P_xy.value.reshape(X_max,-1))
```

Comment: This problem does not make much sense to me,but the important message here is: **use sparse-matrices**. None of those backend-solvers would use dense-matrices anyway. Optimization without exploiting sparsity is well... rare. Lookup the lp standard-form to see, that each of your constraint will be a row with only 2 nonzero-entries and then compare some dense-matrix and some csr_format. Also important: not only store sparsely, but also work/build sparsely. See [example](https://github.com/sschnug/kemeny_ranking/blob/master/kemeny.py#L125) which is somewhat similar (transitivity constr).

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your comment. It solved my problem with the memory. The problem is synthetic and doesn't make much sense. I've used it as a minimal example for my original problem that has lots of more constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @sascha I have re-wrote the code using  `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` and the memory problem has solved.

I post the modified code here:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

np.random.seed(55)
X_max, Y_max, Z_max = 70, 70, 50

P_yz = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(Y_max, Z_max), p=[9./10, 1./10])
P_yz = P_yz.reshape(-1)

row = []
col = []
for x in range(X_max):
  for y in range(Y_max):
    for z in range(Z_max):
      ids = np.unravel_index(np.ravel_multi_index((x,y,z,x,y), (X_max, Y_max, Z_max, X_max, Y_max)), (X_max * Y_max * Z_max, X_max * Y_max))
      row.append(ids[0])
      col.append(ids[1])
z_repetition_sparse = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(len(row)), (row, col)), shape=(X_max * Y_max * Z_max, X_max * Y_max))

row = []
col = []
for x in range(X_max):
  for y in range(Y_max):
    for z in range(Z_max):
      ids = np.unravel_index(np.ravel_multi_index((x,y,z,y,z), (X_max, Y_max, Z_max, Y_max, Z_max)), (X_max * Y_max * Z_max, Y_max * Z_max))
      row.append(ids[0])
      col.append(ids[1])
x_repetition_sparse = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(len(row)), (row, col)), shape=(X_max * Y_max * Z_max, Y_max * Z_max))

P_xy = cp.Variable((X_max * Y_max), boolean=True)
constraints = [] 
constraints.append(z_repetition_sparse * P_xy >= sp.csr_matrix.dot(x_repetition_sparse, P_yz))
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.sum(P_xy)), constraints) 
objective = problem.solve(verbose=True)
print(P_xy.value.reshape(X_max,-1))
```